# Getting a undefined value even though passing INT in react, express, zod

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, zod

**Issue with Passing Integer Values to Backend Server and Zod Validation Error**

I'm encountering an issue with passing integer values from a React frontend to a backend server. Despite correctly passing integer values through a POST request, the Zod validation on the backend keeps returning an error stating 'undefined'. I'm unsure why this validation is failing despite passing the appropriate data.

[encountering error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1SGA.png)

Here's a snippet of my React frontend component responsible for handling the input and sending the data:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function CreateInput() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [calorie, setCalorie] = useState("");
    const [protein, setProtein] = useState("");
    const [carbs, setCarbs] = useState("");

    const inputStyle = {
        marginBottom: '10px',
        padding: '8px',
        borderRadius: '5px',
        border: '1px solid #ccc',
        fontSize: '16px',
        width: '250px',
        boxSizing: 'border-box'
    };

    const buttonStyle = {
        padding: '8px 16px',
        borderRadius: '5px',
        backgroundColor: '#4CAF50',
        color: 'white',
        border: 'none',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        fontSize: '16px'
    };

    const containerStyle = {
        textAlign: 'center'
    };

    const handleAddFood = async () => {
        // Validation to ensure fields are not empty
        if (!name || !calorie || !protein || !carbs) {
            alert("Please fill in all fields");
            return;
        }

        // Convert the values to integers
        const calorieInt = parseInt(calorie);
        const proteinInt = parseInt(protein);
        const carbsInt = parseInt(carbs);

        // Check if parsing was successful
        if (isNaN(calorieInt) || isNaN(proteinInt) || isNaN(carbsInt)) {
            alert("Calorie, protein, and carbs must be numbers");
            return;
        }

        const now = new Date();
        const year = now.getFullYear();
        const month = String(now.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        const day = String(now.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        const hours = String(now.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
        const minutes = String(now.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
        const seconds = String(now.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');
        
        const formattedDateTime = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
        
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/inputfood', {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    date: formattedDateTime,
                    eat: {
                        name: name,
                        calorie: calorieInt,
                        protein: proteinInt,
                        carbs: carbsInt,
                    }
                })
            });            
            
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            
            const data = await response.json();
            alert("Food Added");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error adding food:', error);
            alert("Failed to add food");
        }
    };

    return (
        <div style={containerStyle}>
            <input style={inputStyle} type="text" placeholder="Input Name" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} /><br />
            <input style={inputStyle} type="number" placeholder="Input Calorie cal" onChange={(e) => setCalorie(e.target.value)} /><br />
            <input style={inputStyle} type="number" placeholder="Input Protein g" onChange={(e) => setProtein(e.target.value)} /><br />
            <input style={inputStyle} type="number" placeholder="Input Carbs g" onChange={(e) => setCarbs(e.target.value)} /><br />
            <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={handleAddFood}>Add Food</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Could anyone help me understand why the Zod validation on the backend is returning 'undefined' despite passing integer values correctly? I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: In your zod schema you wrote `proteins` but when making the request you are passing `protein`. Same goes for `calorie` and `calories`.